# change icon when mouse hover over push button in qt

Tags: qt, button, icons, mousehover

I am trying to change the icon of a push button in qt when mouse hover over it. But i couldn't find any useful example about it. If anyone can help by posting a little example please. I've found examples on QEvent::MouseMove and hoverenter and hoverleave events concerning this subject but I didn't succed in using them

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22458-Change-button-Icon-on-toggle)?

Comment: There is nothing about mouse hover event in the link below... my problem is not in setting the icon, but in initializing the mouse hover event. Thank you anyway for your help

Comment: the title of your question is misleading then and I would recommend changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find those examples useful:

1) Using QSS->

```
QPushButton {
    border-image: url(:/icons/normal);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    border-image: url(:/icons/hover);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

2) Update stylesheet from code->

```
button->setStyleSheet( "*{border-image: url(:/icons/normal);} 
:hover{ border-image: url(:/icons/hover);}");
```

Don't forget to locate your images in the resources folder.
Good luck :)